# How does 结果发现 work?

Tags: grammar

I was reading the HSK6 Standard Course workbook (chapter 31), and it has the sentence ([photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Y7dl.jpg)):

> **结果发现**，与“不爱思考的人”相比，“爱思考的人”的活动要少很多。

This is puzzling to me: 结果 = "results" (n.) is the subject, and the verb is 发现 = "discover" (v.).  It seems like 结果 is unable to 发现 something, as 结果 has no sensory organs nor ability to think.  Even more confusing: it seems that what the 结果 is discovering is itself (结果发现自己).  It seems like it should say 结果显示 or 结果是 or maybe 结果包括.

**Question**: How does 结果发现 work?

Comment: Yes, it should be 结果显示. Human can 发现, 结果 cannot 发现 anything.

Answer (score 2):

> Question: How does 结果发现 work?

1. 结果 = at the end; 结果发现 = discovered at the end
2. There are omission (根據)结果(研究員)发现 = (according to) results (researchers) found

Example of "结果 = at the end"

**结果**不了了之 = No resolution was pursued **at the end**

Answer (score 1):

Based on the text in the [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Y7dl.jpg), I think the complete sentence would be:

研究人员从**结果**中**发现**，与“不爱思考的人”相比，“爱思考的人”的活动要少很多。【1】

**结果**研究人员**发现**，与“不爱思考的人”相比，“爱思考的人”的活动要少很多。【2】

【1】结果 is a noun, the result of an action.

【2】结果 is an adverb, at the end of an action. For example,

老师又给我们讲了一遍，结果还是没有一个同学明白。

【3】结果 is a verb, to put an end to something. For example,

黑帮老大说，你去结果了他！（to kill）。

Answer (score 1):

发现 can mean "discovery." Therefore, 结果发现 can be taken as "the results of discovery."

Alternatively, 结果 can mean "in the end."

Example: 結果是秦國蕩平六合，統一中原。In the end, Qin eliminated the other six countries and reunified the country.

Answer (score 1):

结果发现，可以理解成“最后发现”，或者理解成，“从结果中发现”的省略表达。

Answer (score 0):

Similar wording is found in English, i.e.:

- results revealed

Here's a quick and dirty example to give an instance:

[Mechanism of Nur77-mediated mitophagy](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Mechanism-of-Nur77-mediated-mitophagy-Our-results-revealed-that-damaged-mitochondria_fig1_316976122)

> Our results revealed that damaged mitochondria resulted from inflammation insult could lead to chronic inflammation associated with the development of cancer and other inflammatory diseases.

"结果发现" works just the same as "results revealed" here.

---

It may be easier just to memorize it as a single term:

[Reverso](https://context.reverso.net/%E7%BF%BB%E8%AF%91/%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87-%E8%8B%B1%E8%AF%AD/%E7%BB%93%E6%9E%9C%E5%8F%91%E7%8E%B0)

> turns out

Comment: results revealed = 结果显示

Answer (score 0):

zdic.net has this definition of 发现

(4) 由于对一个目标的研究或经验而找到

科学研究几乎每天都在发现重要的新原理。
Scientific research is discovering important new principles almost every day.

You could argue, 'scientific research' can't do anything, because it is an abstraction. The scientists actually discover things, not the research. However, language works in metaphors. I don't think anyone would be unable to understand the above sentence.

Equally, 结果发现 is easily understood, as Mou pointed out.

The argument that a lot of words have been omitted is a supposition which cannot be shown to be true.